# The structure of the sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, dummy-pronouns, functions, extraposition

> It takes the earth a little more than 365 days to travel around the sun.

According to the sentence, I think the structure of it like the following:

- It = Preparatory "it"
- takes = Verb
- the earth = Indirect object
- a little more than 365 days = Direct object
- to travel around the sun = Subject

If there is something wrong, please explain it to me.

Comment: You are right except that "it" is the subject, **not** the infinitival clause "to travel around the sun" This is called an 'extraposed' construction where the subject of the basic (non-extraposed) version is 'extraposed' to the end of the sentence, outside the verb phrase, and replaced by the dummy pronoun "it" which becomes the subject. The basic version would be _To travel around the sun takes the earth a little more than 365 days_.

Comment: Bill, can't the "**it**" be a **dummy-it** and the sentence be understood as "*The Earth travels around the sun in a little more than 365 days*"?

Comment: However, even "*The Earth takes a little more than 365 days to travel around the sun*" is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

> - *It takes the earth a little more than 365 days to travel around the sun.*

*It* **is** the subject of this example sentence, but that's the only easy part. This example sentence is a transformation of an original sentence

- *[For **the earth** to travel around the sun] [takes a little more than 365 days].*

The subject of this original sentence is the subordinate infinitive complement clause *for **the earth** to travel around the sun,* which has ***the earth*** as its subject (keep your eye on that noun phrase ***the earth***; it's gonna move around). The verb phrase of this original sentence is the construction *takes a little more than 365 days*, which is an idiom referring to the perceived temporal duration of its subject.

This original sentence is transformed by [Extraposition](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/57519/15299) (which adds the dummy subject *It*, and moves the original infinitive clause subject to the end of the sentence) into:

- ***It*** [takes a little more than 365 days] [for **the earth** to travel around the sun].

This resulting sentence (which is completely grammatical and means the same thing as the original) is then transformed **again** by raising ***the earth***, the subject  of the infinitive clause, to become the object of *take*, the verb of the main clause. This moves it over the time phrase to follow *takes*, producing the example sentence (which is **also** perfectly grammatical and means the same thing as the other two):

- ***It*** takes **the earth** a little more than 365 days to travel around the sun.

What you want to call the various constituents of these sentence is between you and your English teacher. But labelling things does not help much in using or understanding English, unless one has **all** the labels to refer to.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is like this:

- It = Subject
- takes = verb in third person of singular (it)
- the earth = indirect object
- al little more than 365 days = Direct object
- to travel around the sun = Complement

You can check [this](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-direct-indirect-object.php) out

Comment: If "it" is the subject, what does "it" refer to?

Comment: I think it refers to the action of taking a little more than 365 days.

Comment: You are right, except that the infinitval clause "to travel around the sun" is not a complement, but an extraposed subject outside the verb phrase. Please see my message to the OP.

Comment: Can you explain me the infinite clause? @BillJ What do you mean by OP?

Comment: 'OP' means 'original poster'; the person who asked the question in the first place. In this case, the OP is thein Iwin.

Comment: Ohh thanks for telling me! Do you have some link to read more about you explained here? @BillJ

Comment: The infinitival clause "to travel around the sun" is the subject in the basic non-extraposed version. In the extraposed construction, the subject of the basic version is moved to the end of the sentence and is called 'the displaced subject'. It is outside the VP (verb phrase). Here's a link that may help you: [link](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/internet-grammar/function/extra.htm)

Comment: Wow, I will save your comment to search a little more about what you said. Thanks for answering me again, learning is what matters and it's better if people share their knowledge with others! @BillJ

Comment: What grammar book do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43412/discussion-between-manuel-sayago-and-billj).

Comment: "It" does not refer at all in this kind of sentence.

Comment: [correction: can you explain x to me, not explain me].